# passing generic list from jquery to c# code-behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, jquery-ui

I have a simple webmethod , which is basically filtering the reports in my code-behind :-

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static List<Report> FetchReports(string reportName)
    {
        List<Report> FetchedReports = dataModel.PopulateLinks().Where(r => r.Name.ToLower().Contains(reportName.ToLower())).ToList();
        return FetchedReports;
    }
```

Now this is returned to this Jquery function:-

```
        $("#reports-textSearch").keyup(function () {
        var textLength = $(this).val().length;
        if (textLength > 2) {
            var args = {
                reportName: document.getElementById('reports-textSearch').value
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Dashboard.aspx/FetchReports",
                data: JSON.stringify(args),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(r) {
                    var reports = r.data;
                    $.each(reports, function (index, report) {
                        $("#div1").append("<strong>" + report.Name + "</strong>" + "<br/>" +
                        "ID: " + report.Id + "<br />" +
                        "DisplayName: " + report.DisplayName + "<br />" +
                        "Url: " + report.Url + "<br />" +
                        "ParentId: " + report.ParentId + "<br />" +
                        "ReportGroupId: " + report.ReportGroupId + "<br />" +
                        "AccessLevel: " + report.AccessLevel + "<br />");
                        alert(reports);
                    });
                    //var reports = data.d;
                    //__doPostBack('div#UPMainMenu', reports());
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

and I wish to submit it back to another page, from where I will get the result of the search and populate another panel.

At the moment this code does not work, how can I change the $.each part of the code, to return an actual List, and how can I then manipulate that in the C# code-behind to get the desired filtered reports?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

hi please follow this detail article to know how to pass parameters frm jquery to code behind.

[Jquery and WCF](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service)